# How to detect Click + [Shift, Ctrl, Alt] in reactjs click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do some other things when user Click+[Ctrl], but it seems that I could not detect if user press Ctrl when clicking.

I copy the event object infos below.

```
bubbles    :    false
cancelBubble    :    false
cancelable    :    false
currentTarget    :    react
defaultPrevented    :    false
eventPhase    :    2
isTrusted    :    false
path    :    Array[1]
returnValue    :    true
srcElement    :    react
target    :    react
timeStamp    :    5690056.695
type    :    "react-click"
```

I can see the ctrlKey attribute in the arguments[0]-Proxy Object. But this object is unaccessable('Uncaught illegal access'):

```
[[Target]]
:
SyntheticMouseEvent
_dispatchInstances:ReactDOMComponent
_dispatchListeners:(e)
_targetInst:ReactDOMComponent
altKey:false
bubbles:true
button:0
buttons:0
cancelable:true
clientX:275
clientY:315
ctrlKey:false
```

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355913/2969544)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your click handling function would have a format as such:

```
clickHandler: function (event, value) {

   event.stopPropagation();

   // In that case, event.ctrlKey does the trick.
   if (event.ctrlKey) {
        console.debug("Ctrl+click has just happened!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code below in your render() method

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('With ctrl, do something...');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

In the `click` event of this element you can check if at the moment of the click, a button (with `keycode` of `ctrl` in this case) is pressed down