# Call function on keydown (Ctrl + Enter) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an app and I want to fire a function (in this case the `showMessage`) when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
How would I do this, preferably without jQuery?

```
import React from "react"

const App = React.createClass({
  showMessage () {
    console.log('hit');
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.showMessage}>Hit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


module.exports = App;
```

Comment: Register `onkeypress` handler for the document in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. add event listener: `document.addEventListener('keydown',this.keydownHandler)`
2. then in handler check `e.keyCode===13 && e.ctrlKey`
3. don't forget to remove event listener in `componentWillUnmount`

```js
const App = React.createClass({
  showMessage () {
    alert('SOME MESSAGE');
  },
  keydownHandler(e){
    if(e.keyCode===13 && e.ctrlKey) this.showMessage()
  },
  componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener('keydown',this.keydownHandler);
  },
  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener('keydown',this.keydownHandler);
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Press Ctrl+Enter</h1>
        <button onClick={this.showMessage}>Hit</button>
      </div>`
    );
  }
});
export default App;
```

Comment: Perfect. Just added it to my project and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: `keyCode` is now deprecated. Use `e.key === 'Enter' && e.ctrlKey` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Can also be done using functional components too

```js
export function App() {
  const showMessage = () => {
    alert('SOME MESSAGE');
  };
  const keydownHandler = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter' && e.ctrlKey) showMessage()
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Press Ctrl+Enter</h1>
      <button onClick={showMessage}>Hit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```